# Accessing iframe with different port

Tags: http, iframe, port

A machine with IP `10.120.11.101` has two webservers, and I can access them independently from my browser.

- One at http://10.120.11.101:19531/browse
- A second at http://10.120.11.101/logs (port 80 by default)

When the browser views the second website (i.e. port 80), how come this works:

```
<iframe src="http//10.120.11.101:19531/browse" id="logs"></iframe>
```

and this works:

```
<iframe src="//10.120.11.101:19531/browse" id="logs"></iframe>
```

but this does not work?:

```
<iframe src=":19531/browse" id="logs"></iframe>
```